# Multiple IF statements - PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, power-platform

I am looking to filter a drop down list from 2 other drop down lists. I currently have it working from just one of the lists as follows:

```
If(IsBlank(('ComboBox1'.SelectedItems)) || IsEmpty('ComboBox1'.SelectedItems), SortByColumns(GroupBy(List,"Title","Name"),"Title",SortOrder.Ascending), SortByColumns(GroupBy(Filter(List, 'ComboBox1'.Selected.ListName = 'ListName'),"Title","Name"),"Title",SortOrder.Ascending))
```

I now need to essentially include the same IF statement again, as an or condition. So If the above or if the same again with ComboBox2. However I am not sure how to do this.

I have tried to do it as first IF || second IF but no luck.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain more about your requirements? Do you want to show records from `List`  based on both combo boxes? Or only one combo box conditionally like - If `ComboBox1` is empty, show records based on `ComboBox2` else show records based on `ComboBox1`. If both are empty, show all records from `List`?

Comment: I am looking to show all list items if both combo boxes are empty/blank, however if combobox1 is used I need the list to filter and sort by that selection, but if combobox2 is used I need it to filter by that selection. It is not likely for both combobox1 and 2 to be used together as they will be used by different sets of users.

Comment: check below answer. let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding from your question and comment(s) above, try using formula like given below:

```
If(
    IsBlank('ComboBox1'.SelectedItems) || IsEmpty('ComboBox1'.SelectedItems),
    If(
        IsBlank('ComboBox2'.SelectedItems) || IsEmpty('ComboBox2'.SelectedItems),
        SortByColumns(
            GroupBy(List, "Title", "Name"),
            "Title",
            SortOrder.Ascending
        ),
        SortByColumns(
            GroupBy(Filter(List, 'ComboBox2'.Selected.ListName = 'ListName'), "Title", "Name"),
            "Title",
            SortOrder.Ascending
        )
    ),
    SortByColumns(
        GroupBy(Filter(List, 'ComboBox1'.Selected.ListName = 'ListName'), "Title", "Name"),
        "Title",
        SortOrder.Ascending
    )
)
```

Comment: Perfect , Thank you that seems to have done the trick.